# Simple bytes loaded programm gets runtime error (Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am creating simple programm that needs to trace out bytesLoaded and bytesTotal. It looks that everything is okay, but I get this runtime error: ***Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.*** This is my as3.0 class code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;

   public class shoolWork3 extends MovieClip {
       public function shooWork3():void {
           addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadProgress);

        function loadProgress(event:Event) {
            // get bytes loaded and bytes total
            var movieBytesLoaded:int = this.root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
            var movieBytesTotal:int = this.root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;

            //Convert to kilobytes
            var gameKilobytesLoaded:int = gameBytesLoaded / 1024;
            var gameKilobytesTotal:int = gameBytesTotal / 1024;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function, `this` is refering to the `global` object scope, not to the class, and on the `global` object there is no `root` property, hence the error. If you want to access properties of the class, then you have to remove the `this` keyword.

```
var movieBytesLoaded:int = root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
...
```

Also your variables are called `movieBytesLoaded` and `movieBytesTotal`, but you are trying to access `gameBytesLoaded` and `gameBytesTotal`, that won't work too.

Comment: Good catch! It's worth noting that this is happening because the OP has defined the event handling function `loadProgress()` inside of his constructor method. Note that if you run this code in the debugger, you will see that `this` refers to AS3's "global" object. It's different from Javascript, where I assume `this` would refer to the function. Another solution to make this code work, is to declare `loadProgress()` as a method of the `SchoolWork3` class. Doing it this way might be more desirable: it's the usual pattern in AS3, and makes it easy to remove the event listener later.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's not even like that in JavaScript :) Actually, in JavaScript the OPs code would work, `this` would refer to the `Window` object, but before trying to access the referenced property on that object it would check the current functions scope, and then the parent functions scope. I'll correct my answer.